# what the "this" represent in "this.model('Animal')" and "this.type" in the following code?

Tags: node.js, mongoose

hey i am new in mongoose and node.i am little bit confuse in following code :

```
 var animalSchema = new Schema({ name: String, type: String });

 animalSchema.methods.findSimilarTypes = function (cb) {
    return this.model('Animal').find({ type: this.type }, cb);
}

var Animal = mongoose.model('Animal', animalSchema);
var dog = new Animal({ type: 'dog' });
dog.findSimilarTypes(function (err, dogs) {
console.log(dogs);
});
```

what the `this` instance represent in `this.model('Animal')` and `this.type` in the following code ?

Comment: The first `this` is `animalSchema` and the second the model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In an instance method like `findSimilarTypes`, `this` is the model instance of the document from the database.

So `this.model('Animal')` is looking up the `Animal` model, and `this.type` is the `type` property of the model instance used when calling `findSimilarTypes`.